# Angular2 with Protractor - browser.pause just sits

Tags: angular, protractor

I've seen this bug appear and disappear before, but can't seem to isolate it. Using the [Protractor configuration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CarmenPopoviciu/angular2-go-protractor/master/protractor.conf.js) from Angular 2 Go Protractor, if I insert a `browser.pause()` it's like an extra line appears after the `wd-debug` prompt and it doesn't respond to commands.

Here is the output:

```
[1] [16:15:07] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[1] [16:15:07] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[1] Started
[1]
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor -
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor - Encountered browser.pause(). Attaching debugger...
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor -
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor - ------- WebDriver Debugger -------
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor - Starting WebDriver debugger in a child process. Pause is still beta, please report issues at github.com/angular/protractor
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor -
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor - press c to continue to the next webdriver command
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor - press ^D to detach debugger and resume code execution
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor - type "repl" to enter interactive mode
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor - type "exit" to break out of interactive mode
[1] [16:15:09] I/protractor -
[1] Starting debugger agent.
[1] Debugger listening on port 5858
[1] ControlFlow::486
[1] | TaskQueue::182
[1] | | (pending) Task::184<then>
[1] | | | TaskQueue::459
[1] | | | | (pending) Task::461<Run it("foo") in control flow>
[1] | | | | | TaskQueue::464
[1] | | | | | | (blocked) Task::470<<anonymous>>
[1] | | | | Task::463<then>
[1] wd-debug>
(blank line here)
```

It even happens with just an empty test:

```
describe('Foo Component', () => {


  beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get('');
  });

  it('foo', () => {
    browser.pause();
  });
});
```

The first time I encountered this, I thought I had fixed it by copying the Angular 2 Go Protractor configuration, and I could have sworn the problem even reappeared when I reverted back to my old configuration, and disappeared when I put back the Angular 2 Go Protractor config. But now the problem is appearing again, and I've verified that it's using that config now.

Has anyone else seen this?